# Unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'str' and 'int' when formatting a SQL result

Tags: python

I would like to format the result of an SQL query:

Original data:

| name | days |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 60 |
| Bob | 52 |
| Mike | 266 |
| Lucas | 27 |

Expected formatted data:

| name | days |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | 2 |
| Bob | 1 22/30 |
| Mike | 8 26/30 |
| Lucas | 27/30 |

With the code below I get: `unsupported operand type(s) for divmod():`

```py
def get_days(days):
    quotient, modulus = divmod(days, 30)
    if modulus:
        return "{} {}/30".format(quotient, modulus)
    else:
        return str(int(quotient))
    
def get_baby_detail(id_):
    data = db.session.query(Baby.name, Baby.days).filter(Baby.id == id_).first()
    got_days = get_days(data.days)
    return dict(data, days=got_days)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `days` in the `get_days` function? Use `print(type(days))`. This is probably of the type `str` and `divmod` is expecting an `int`. You need to convert the `str` type to an `int`: `quotient, modulus = divmod(int(days), 30)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two series, named `months` and `day_in_month`. Then, format them based on the conditions you have.

```
months = df.days // 30

day_in_month = df.days - (months * 30)

conditions = [
    (months == 0) & (day_in_month == 0),
    (months == 0) & (day_in_month != 0),
    (months != 0) & (day_in_month == 0)
]

values = [np.nan, day_in_month.astype(str).add('/30'), months]

default = months.astype(str).add(' ').add(day_in_month.astype(str)).add('/30')

df['days_formatted'] = np.select(conditions, values, default)
```

Output

```
    name  days days_formatted
0  Alice    60              2
1    Bob    52        1 22/30
2   Mike   266        8 26/30
3  Lucas    27          27/30
```